# Getting org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9300]][cluster/nodes/info] disconnected

Tags: java, spring, maven, elasticsearch

I am New in Elastic Search Java Api[5.0]. I am Using elasticsearch-5.0.0.
I am try to create a Java Application(Maven) with Spring Boot. After run Application, it shows

```
2016-11-04 23:32:19.339  INFO 8280 --- [][generic][T#2]]      org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [X-Ray] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][DESKTOP-8SIPHSN][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9300]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9300]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info] disconnected
```

My Config File Is

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Client client() {

        TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
        TransportAddress address = new  InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost",9300);
        client.addTransportAddress(address);        
        return client;
    }

}
```

And I am using default cluster "elasticsearch". I need help to solve my issue with proper detection of causes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `PreBuiltTransportClient` mentioned in the 5.0 documentation:

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html

Also note that the `TransportClient` for ES version 2.x isn't compatible with 5.x:

> The client must have the same major version (e.g. 2.x, or 5.x) as the
>   nodes in the cluster. Clients may connect to clusters which have a
>   different minor version (e.g. 2.3.x) but it is possible that new
>   functionality may not be supported. Ideally, the client should have
>   the same version as the cluster.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

**Update**

As a connectivity test, try executing the following simple program:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        // The following settings aren't strictly necessary, because the default cluster name is "elasticsearch".
        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
        System.out.println(client.connectedNodes());
    }
}
```

It should print to stdout something like the following line:

`[{luhcORJ}{luhcORJOSzSLPBeXocDsuQ}{mkTJpwIAQGuNYTHfRLqUIw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]`

Comment: i am using 
       `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: I am Trying to this code
    `TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));`
but  Settings.EMPTY  showing Error

Comment: Did you rename your cluster?  If it's something other than `elasticsearch`, you need to specify that in the `cluster.name` property in the `TransportClient` settings.

Comment: I can't Specify why, Showing Settings.EMPTY error, 
I am Trying both default cluster name and rename cluster. When I rename cluster name, and set it 
`Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "geo-location").build();

            TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));`
Then it shows  Settings.builder() as error.
Here i am using this package `import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;`

Comment: Hello @ck1 can you explain  me why i am get error **Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "geo-location").build();** ?

Comment: I've updated my test program above to create a `Settings` instance.  If this doesn't work for you, can you paste the specific exception that you're seeing?

Comment: `@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {

        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "geo-location").build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).
                addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
      

        return client;
    }


}`

Comment: Information:11/5/2016 9:55 AM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 12s 217ms
E:\ElasticSearchProject\GeoSearch\src\main\java\com\location\configuration\ElasticsearchConfiguration.java
Error:(25, 37) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: interface org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings
Information:java: E:\ElasticSearchProject\GeoSearch\src\main\java\com\location\configuration\ElasticsearchConfiguration.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Information:java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Thanks @ck1,Finally it works. But can't define my problem what was. I just recreate a project and paste your update code.