# PrebuiltTransportClient import without Maven

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

So in my previous question I explained how I am working on a Spring project without Maven that needs to use elasticsearch 5.1.1. Thanks to your help I have managed to import elastic search, and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429631/getting-org-elasticsearch-transport-nodedisconnectedexception-inetlocalhost) I'm trying to create a TransportClient. My current code is:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

The problem appears to be that the import for the PreBuiltTransportClient is not at that location anymore. Does anyone know where I can import PreBuiltTransportClient from? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046172/using-prebuilttransportclient-with-elasticsearch-5

Comment: That would work if I was using Maven, but this project isn't so I can't add those dependencies. Still thanks for the link.

Comment: What do you use to manage your dependencies?

Comment: We use a library folder in our Web-inf directory to store all of our jar files.

Comment: Yes, for sure, but how do you get those JARs in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply follow these steps:

1. go to the [MVN repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport/5.1.1) for the `org.elasticsearch.client » transport » 5.1.1` dependency
2. click "Download JAR"
3. save that JAR into your WEB-INF/lib folder
4. repackage your WAR and deploy it
5. Enjoy

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much!